# How to identify Nextjs prefetch request in the middleware

Tags: next.js, middleware, prefetch

I'm trying to identify the prefetch requests made by next.js in the middleware so that the my custom logic only runs when users navigates between pages.

So I tried to look for the different request headers in the request and try to make distinction between requests

Comment: You can filter out any request that starts with `/_next/`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the following headers in the request in Next 13, maybe you can also target them as an option:

```
purpose: prefetch
x-middleware-prefetch: 1
x-nextjs-data: 1
```

You can also ignore some routes with the matcher:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matching-paths

Comment: I'm on NextJs13 and none of them is changing from a client request and a prefetching request.. They return null everytime

Comment: None of these headers seem to be useful in the latest NextJS.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer for NextJS 13, I found this header to be useful to detect prefetch requests from Next Router:

```
Next-Router-Prefetch: 1
```